# Apache commons CSV gives error when quote and escape character is same

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

Consider I have a CSV file with record as follows:

```
firstname,lastname
"""amogh""",Kelula
```

here, in first row the first name should be enclosed in double quotes so after parsing in java the record should look like `"amogh", Kelula` and hence it's escaped with two double quotes as quote and escape both are double quotes.

When I try to parse this CSV file using Apache Commons CSV, I configured `CSVFormat` as below:

```
CSVFormat.DEFAULT.builder()
.setDelimiter(delimiter)
.setQuote(quoteCharacter) // quoteCharacter="
.setEscape(escapeCharacter) // escapeCharacter="
.setSkipHeaderRecord(false)
.setAllowMissingColumnNames(true)
.setNullString("")
.build();
```

This gives error when reading the row which has `"""` in the data. The exception is:

> java.io.IOException: (startline 2) EOF reached before encapsulated token finished.

I do not understand why Apache Commons CSV fails to parse this file. Other parsers like PapaParser successfully parse this file without any error. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default CSVFormat (CSVFormat.DEFAULT) should work for triple quoted values.

```
for (CSVRecord record : CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(reader)) {
    System.out.println(record.toList().toString());
}
```

The above code prints out the correct values with the reader being a reader for a CSV file of the contents you provided:

```
firstname,lastname
"""amogh""",Kelula
```

I have deleted my old answer for clarity.

Comment: Yes, this worked as expected. Though I am curious to know how and why this worked?

Comment: I can't tell you, haven't worked Apache commons CSV before. I just tried it since i thought it would work, and it did...